# Swift - Getting GPS coordinates from didUpdateLocations taking too long to return values

Tags: ios, swift, gps

Problem: I need the location coordinates to be acquired before getReports() is executed in viewDidLoad(). As you can see, I'm calling startLocationUpdates first in viewDidLoad(). Unfortunately, there is a delay between calling startLocationUpdates() and didUpdateLocations getting called. This delay is causing the latitude and longitude coordinates to be zero every time prior to executing getReports().

How can I be sure that didUpdateLocations gets called BEFORE getReports() so that the latitude and longitude values are set properly?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.startLocationUpdates()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.mapView.delegate = self

    if mblnLocationAcquired {
        getReports()
    }

    }

}

func startLocationUpdates() {
    var currentLocation = CLLocation()

    mLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    mLocationManager.delegate = self
    //mLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    mLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    mLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    let location = locations.last as CLLocation
    self.mdblLat = location.coordinate.latitude
    self.mdblLong = location.coordinate.longitude

    println("didUpdateLocation  \(location.coordinate.latitude), \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
    mLocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    mblnLocationAcquired = true
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you call getReports from didUpdateLocations (after calling stopUpdatingLocation) instead of in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I thought about that. However, the didUpdateLocations method is called repeatedly even after stopUpdatingLocation is called. I didn't want getReports to get called numerous times in the process.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I be sure that didUpdateLocations gets called BEFORE getReports() so that the latitude and longitude values are set properly?

Simple. Don't call `getReports()` until *after* the latitude and longitude are set properly! You are making a huge mistake by turning off updates as soon as the *first* update arrives. Keep in mind that it takes significant time for the GPS to "warm up" after you start location updates. You will receive numerous initial updates in which the location is meaningless or miles off. You need to use the accuracy reading of the location in order to wait until you have a *good* value before you display anything.

Comment: See my book code for an example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p773location/ch35p1032location/ViewController.swift Notice that I keep checking `horizontalAccuracy` until I get a good enough answer — and _then_ I stop updating. I also am prepared for the possibility that we will _never_ get a good answer (the user might be indoors), in which case I deliberately time out.

Comment: Thanks for the response. For some reason, didUpdateLocations continues to get called repeatedly even after calling stopUpdatingLocations. I thought about calling getReports after didUpdateLocations executes successfully, but if didUpdateLocations gets called repeatedly so will getReports if I set it up that way. Is there any way around this behavior?

Comment: No, `stopUpdatingLocation` does stop the updates. My example to which I pointed you is a downloadable project, so download it and run it, and you will see. If you think you are still getting updates, then something else is going on. You need to rethink the entire structure of your approach in any case. Again look at how my example works.